# Is there a way to generate a map directions image (for fb messenger bot usage)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, maps, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm working on a Facebook Messenger bot for a client and I'm trying to give the users a map with directions to the client's location. I know FB has a button to get the user's location, but I'm not sure how to show the directions.

Any ideas how I might go about doing that because I don't believe Facebook provides something like that by default or as a template message (I could be wrong?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no template for this afaik, but you could just create a picture of the map (and directions) server side. Sending pictures with the bot is no problem at all. It all depends on how exactly you want to show directions, but i guess there is no other option. You can include a list too, showing all the steps/turns to get to the destination.